# Отправка текста на Email android

Tags: android

Как сделать чтобы пользователь писал текст (обратная связь) и его текст отправлялся на почту, чтобы позже можно было на него ответить (т.е. чтобы пользователь отправлял письмо со своей почты)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ это через `Intent`. Вы шлете необходимую информацию:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"receiver@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

При этом вы используете приложение Gmail для данной цели. Но есть и [такие](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/how-to-send-an-email-with-javamail-api-in-android-2fc405441079) способы решения вашего вопроса. Все зависит от ваших целей.